# Access the camera with iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

It seems obvious that some people have been able to figure out how to access the iPhone camera through the SDK (Spore Origins, for example). How can this be done?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to use the `UIImagePickerController` class, basically:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = pickerDelegate
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera
```

The `pickerDelegate` object above needs to implement the following method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

The dictionary `info` will contain entries for the original, and the edited image, keyed with `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` and `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` respectively. (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerinfokey for more details)

Comment: The picker delegate method you mention here is now deprecated in OS 3.0 - http://tinyurl.com/yjlhzcl

Answer (score 5):

Hmmmm.....Ever tried using an OverlayView? With this the camera might look customized but in actuality its just a view above it.

If the private API's are directly accessed it might result in the app being rejected by Apple.
See if the below link helps.

[link text](http://www.articlesbase.com/programming-articles/custom-camera-applications-development-using-iphone-sdk-766832.html)