# How can I take a photo with my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, camera

I'm writing an iPhone app with Cocoa in xcode.  I can't find any tutorials or sample code that shows how to take photos with the built in camera.  How do I do this?  Where can I find good info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Just Copy and paste following code into your project to get fully implemented functionality.

where **takePhoto**  and **chooseFromLibrary**  are my own method names which will be called on button touch.

Make sure to reference outlets of appropriate buttons to these methods.

```
   -(IBAction)takePhoto :(id)sender

{
        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        }

        // image picker needs a delegate,
        [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];

    // Place image picker on the screen
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
}



-(IBAction)chooseFromLibrary:(id)sender
{

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
    [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

    // image picker needs a delegate so we can respond to its messages
    [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];

    // Place image picker on the screen
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];

}

//delegate methode will be called after picking photo either from camera or library
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{   
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [myImageView setImage:image];    // "myImageView" name of any UIImageView.
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `UIImagePickerController`. There is a good tutorial on this here.

http://www.zimbio.com/iPhone/articles/1109/Picking+Images+iPhone+SDK+UIImagePickerController

You should set the source type to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` or `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`. Note that these two types result in very different displays on the screen. You should test both carefully. In particular, if you are nesting the `UIImagePickerController` inside a `UINavigationController`, you can end up with multiple navigation bars and other weird effects if you are not careful.

See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74113/access-the-camera-with-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 4):

The `UIImagePickerController` class lets you take pictures or choose them from the photo library.  Specify the source type as `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`.

See also this question previously asked:
[Access the camera with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74113/access-the-camera-with-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

Answer posted by @WQS works fine, but contains some methods that are deprecated from iOS 6. Here is the updated answer for iOS 6 & above:

```
-(void)takePhoto
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    }

    // image picker needs a delegate,
    [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];

    // Place image picker on the screen
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}



-(void)chooseFromLibrary
{

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController= [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

    // image picker needs a delegate so we can respond to its messages
    [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];

    // Place image picker on the screen
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

//delegate methode will be called after picking photo either from camera or library
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

[myImageView setImage:image];    // "myImageView" name of any UImageView.
}
```

Don't Forget to add this in your `view controller.h` :

```
@interface myVC<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that i used to take picture for my app

```
- (IBAction)takephoto:(id)sender {

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [imageview setImage:img];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

if you want to retake picture just simple add this function

```
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```