# how to take the photo from the iphone using obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hii every one i am new to iphone , can any one tell me the good tutorial link or  example code which shows taking the photo  from the phone & using that taken picture,

thanx in avance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I take a photo with my iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123503/how-can-i-take-a-photo-with-my-iphone-app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070). And also check these tutorials

[Tutorial 1](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/)

[Tutorial 2](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/camera/camera-application-to-take-pictures-and-save-images-to-photo-album.html)

Comment: ur code worked fine , actually my requirement is taking a photo of customer while saving customer details,,in the default contacts iphone app,, how the option is there kone like that i need to do,,i mean on click of that image place it should ask take photo, delete photo, use existing photo,,, how can i do like that