# iPhone:Can my program access Camera using imagepicker API?

Tags: iphone

If my program wants to have a feature which need to access Camera and take photo and come back to app using UIImagePicker (UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera), can my program do that on iPhone, especially on non-jailbroken device? Does Apple allow for such program to upload in AppStore? 
I have seen somewhere that Apple don't allow this(camera access from 3rd party app) if we create such a program. Is it so?

Appreciate your suggestions.

Thanks.

-Prabakar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74113/access-the-camera-with-iphone-sdk

Comment: i cannot understand, why you cannot just use UIImagePicker? it's standart control to make photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `UIImagePickerController` directly:

```
UIImagePickerController *thePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
thePicker.delegate = thePickerDelegate;
thePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

//Here you would present thePicker modally, and release it after this
//It will be deallocated when you remove it from screen
[anotherViewController presentModalViewController: thePicker animated:NO];
[thePicker release];
```

In the `thePickerDelegate`, implement

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo;
```

The `image` is the picture you took, and you can manipulate it as you wish. If you want the `UIImagePickerController` to dissapear after taking one photo, this is where you would trigger this action, and remove it from screen, in the modal case presented above, by calling

```
[thePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO];
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't it a leak if we leave 'thePicker'?

Comment: If we leave it where? Please explain where you believe to be a leak.

Comment: I am asking where do we need to release 'thePicker' if we allocate like below? Can i release it in end of 'didFinishPickingImage'?
UIImagePickerController *thePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

Comment: Oh, I see, well, I didn't write the whole showing the picker - releasing the picker part, because you may want to add it to a navigation controller, a tab bar, as a child of another view, or display it modally. Of course that you should release it after adding it to the screen one way or another.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the modal presentation and removal of the picker.