# iPhone - Using CALayers instead of UIViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, drawing, calayer

I've always been told that if you want to display things into a view, you must add subviews into it and then draw into those subviews.

And today, I see that question (searching for something else) : [IPhone SDK: Camera access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558276/iphone-sdk-camera-access)

In the accepted answer, I see that its author uses CALayers to draw 4 sub "views" into the main view, but all of this only based on CALayers...

So I wonder... Why ? Is this a correct way of doing ? What could lead me to use seblayers instead of subviews ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using both UIViews and CALayers. It really depends on what you want and need. UIView uses CALayer in the background, so you're using CALayers in either case. Note that there's a layer property in UIView of the type CALayer. However, coding directly with UIView is easier but it doesn't expose the full powers of Core Animation. Coding with CALayer does expose you to Core Animation and a dozen of other APIs.

If you're just concerned adding subviews, either approach would work. You can think UIView hides some of the CALayer implementation details.