# How do I take a screenshot in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access the camera with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74113/access-the-camera-with-iphone-sdk)

How do I take a photograph in an iPhone app?

Which API can I use?

Please provide sample code.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Access The Camera with iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74113/access-the-camera-with-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Please search before posting new questions. This question is a duplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74113/access-the-camera-with-iphone-sdk

Comment: screenshot of application or camera photo?

Answer (score 2):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *saveImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(saveImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), &context);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// saving image in documents folder
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(saveImage);
NSString *imageName = @"temp.png";

NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
[imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];
```