# Accessing camera and placing a button - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating an application that is similar to the camera app provided in the iPhone. When the user launches the application, the camera should pop out, But i need a button to be displayed on the camera's view. (Similar to the slider provided in the camera app).

1.) Can this be done ?
2.) Are there any tutorials on this ? sample code to begin or any suggestions that might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your answers:

1. Yes.
2. http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273  //Sample code is in the tutorial.

Mark it correct if it helps.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create your overlay camera view. Just set `yourPicker.showsCameraControls=NO;` and pass your view to your picker camera overlay view:   `yourPicker.cameraOverlayView=yourView;`

Comment: Ok, then the defult camera app provides the focus by touch feature, so if i use a overlay view will the focus by touch feature still work ?

Comment: moreover you can add an action to a button that is inside your overlayview that calls `[self.picker takePicture];`...this because `showsCameraControls` is set to NO.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done.

First checkout [Access the camera with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74113/access-the-camera-with-iphone-sdk) for accessing the camera.

Next adding a button can be achieved by setting `cameraOverlayView` property